# PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I run this command in my terminal, It throws this error.
Actually I had a product table but I deleted it. Then why it is not allowing me to create product table?

```
$ php artisan make:migration create_products_table
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the
> name is already in use in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database\migrations\2020_08_26_063223_create_users_table.php
> on line 37
>
> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
>
> Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already
> in use
>
> at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database\migrations\2020_08_26_063223_create_users_table.php:37
> 33|     public function down()
> 34|     {
> 35|         Schema::dropIfExists('users');
> 36|     }
>
> > 37| }
> > 38|
> > 39|
> > 40|
> > 41|
>
> Whoops\Exception\ErrorException
>
> Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already
> in use
>
> at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database\migrations\2020_08_26_063223_create_users_table.php:37
> public function down()
> 34|     {
> 35|         Schema::dropIfExists('users');
> 36|     }
> 37| }
> 38|
> 39|
> 40|
> 41|
>
> 1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php:408
> Whoops\Run::handleError("Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use",
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database\migrations\2020_08_26_063223_create_users_table.php")
>
> 2   [internal]:0
> Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()

Comment: show your `2020_08_26_063223_create_users_table.php` file code.

Comment: HOW did you delete it? Using a migration? Or manually from phpMyAdmin or something like that

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You have another migration with the same name. Check other migration files for the same class name `CreateUsersTable`. I just encountered this issue and fixed it.